# Return nodes together with relations

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I'm playing with `Cypher` and `Neo4j` a bit and I created a simple graph:

```
CREATE (j: person { name: "james" })
CREATE (m: person { name: "mary" })
CREATE (j)<-[:friends_with]-(m)
```

If I return all the nodes:

```
MATCH (m) RETURN m
```

in the graph view I get:

[image]

but the response JSON is:

```
[
  {
    "keys": [
      "m"
    ],
    "length": 1,
    "_fields": [
      {
        "identity": {
          "low": 3,
          "high": 0
        },
        "labels": [
          "person"
        ],
        "properties": {
          "name": "james"
        }
      }
    ],
    "_fieldLookup": {
      "m": 0
    }
  },
  {
    "keys": [
      "m"
    ],
    "length": 1,
    "_fields": [
      {
        "identity": {
          "low": 4,
          "high": 0
        },
        "labels": [
          "person"
        ],
        "properties": {
          "name": "mary"
        }
      }
    ],
    "_fieldLookup": {
      "m": 0
    }
  }
]
```

which contains the list of nodes, but no information about the relationship between nodes.

Is it possible to also get the full graph/the relationship between nodes if certain returned nodes have relationships defined between one another?

Comment: Note that the Neo4j browser by default will execute a secondary query under the hood to get all the relationships that exist between the nodes returned from the query, that's why the relationship information is displayed even though you didn't query for it or return it. You can toggle that behavior off in the browser preferences, there should be a checkbox for "Connect result nodes" or similar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to retrieve relationship information, you must request it in your Cypher request.
For example, if you want to retrieve all the nodes with a `friends_with` relationship

`MATCH (a:person)-[r:friends_with]-(b:person) RETURN a,r,b`

Thus you will recover the nodes and the relationships of the people concerned.
Of course, you can adapt this query, depending on whether you want to know only the original node, only have the relation, etc ...

If you want to get ALL the nodes with an `is_friends` relation:

`MATCH (a)-[r:friends_with]-() RETURN a,r`

So you will turn all the node and the relationship too

Comment: I wasn't aware of the `()` part of the syntax, I think this solves my issue. Thanks!
Side note: theoretically, you can also use `MATCH ()-[r]-() RETURN r` and have all the relationships w/o having to explicitly state the relationship type.

Comment: Yes, the type of relation or even node is by no means obligatory. If this does not appear, it retrieves all the relationships between the nodes indicated (or all the relationships if no node is specified)