# How do I query neo4j to get a node of any class, and surrounded nodes, inlcuding relationship?

Tags: neo4j, cypher, networkx

I am new in neo4j. I wanted to run a query that should return a :person node, and all the surrounding nodes and relationship so that I can form a subgraph from those components.

I have started like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68082323/return-nodes-together-with-relations) But could not go far. My output should look like this,

```
Return CentreNode, OtherNodes, RelationshipsAmongNodesUpToNHops
```

To explain the problem, I am using python networkx for illustration only.

In this example, the original graph looks like this,

```
import os
import sys
import networkx as nx

G1 = nx.karate_club_graph()
nx.draw_networkx(G1)
```

Now lets find an ego_graph centered on node 16, radious 2 and it should look like this,

```
ego_graph = nx.ego_graph(G1, 16, 2)
nx.draw_networkx(ego_graph)
```

My goal is to find (:person) nodes, and ego_graph with radius R, centered on the person nodes. Its a large database, so the there will be many :person nodes (hence many ego_graphs).

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Would the following work for you (replace `n` with an actual max hop)?

```
MATCH (p:Person)
OPTIONAL MATCH path=(p)-[*1..n]->()
RETURN p, collect(path) AS paths
```

Comment: Hi @fbiville, Its actually doing something. But I am still struggling with 2 factors. No 1. I would need to return CentralNode, AllNodes, Paths (3 items). No 2. I how can I control the query for thousand of nodes? I will call this from java/python script where I will process say 1 to 100 central nodes each time? I need to get new central node each time I run the query. Any idea? Thanks a million.

Comment: Sorry for another heads up, this query partially works. Could not figured out how to get the nodes as explained in the original question. <<Return CentreNode, OtherNodes, RelationshipsAmongNodesUpToNHops
>>